# Why are isscalar, isvector and ismatrix all true for A = 1?

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector, scalar

Matlab has the following functions to check inputs:

- [`isscalar`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isscalar.html) to determine whether input is scalar
- [`isvector`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isvector.html) to determine whether input is a vector
- [`ismatrix`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismatrix.html) to determine whether input is a matrix

For `A = 1` (or any "scalar" input) **all** of the above return **`true`**.
Why do I see this counter-intuitive behavior?
And how would I indentify `A = 1` as scalar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't find it counter-intuitive at all. In Mathematics there exist vectors of 1 dimension (even though they are isomorphic with scalars). Also, a matrix can perfectly have size 1x1.

It is true that a single number could be considered a scalar, a 1-vector or a 1x1 matrix. Matlab's view is:

- A scalar is considered to be a 1x1 matrix
- An *n*-vector is just a 1 x *n* or *n* x 1 matrix
- More generally: *trailing singleton dimensions don't count*. For example, a 3D-array of size 2x3x4 can also be considered, say, a 5D-array of size 2x3x4x1x1. This works without error:

  ```
  >> a = rand(2,3,4);
  >> a(2,2,2)
  ans =
      0.2575
  >> a(2,2,2,1,1)
  ans =
      0.2575
  ```

Now, if you want to check if `A` is a vector, matrix, or multidimensional array **with more than one element**, use

```
numel(A)>1
```

The [`numel`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/numel.html) function returns the number of elements of its input argument.

Comment: Additionally, for empty matrices, only `ismatrix` return `true` for `[]`. However, both `ismatrix` and `isvector` return `true` for the empty `zeros(1,0)` or it's transpose. This is right in line with your answer, i.e., `n` can be `0`.

Answer (score 4):

Because Matlab interprets scalars as 1-by-1 **arrays**, see the [`size` documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/size.html).

---

Therefore, depending on your application, you would have to

- use `isscalar` to distinguish a vector from a scalar (because it will return `false` for a vector)
- use `isvector` to distinguish a matrix from a vector (because it will return `false` for a matrix)

Because if you are trying to figure out if a variable is a vector and not a scalar and you use `isvector`, both a scalar and a vector will return `true` - as pointed out in the question.